# jQuery / javascript - Rule for childs except last three

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

It´s been a while since I worked with Js/jQuery deeper. So I hope you can help me:

I want to trigger a function on several elements except on the last three.
Like:

- Element1 - trigger
- Element2 - trigger
- Element3 - trigger
- Element4 - trigger
- Element5 - trigger
- Element6 - no trigger / different trigger
- Element7 - no trigger / different trigger
- Element8 - no trigger / different trigger

The element count is variable. How to do? for? while? jQuery?
I´m too long out of this to get a solution built in my head... :-/

Comment: Well studying some tutorials would be the smart thing to do then wouldn't it? SO is for code problems that you have tried to resolve yourself but ran into problems with .... I see no javascript attempt here whatsoever. Also spend an hour or two going through the jQuery API and all the examples for every method and type of selector

Comment: I know I know. I did make research. Not only for this problem, also for others. I´m in a hurry for this and I didn´t want a perfect solution, just a hint for the right way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length-3; i++) {
  var elem = elems[i];
  // do something with elem
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bertrand! Didn´t test it so far, but your code seems logical to me. On my own I wouldn´t be able to create this at the moment. So thank you much for your help! =)